# Mongoose/MongoDB - updating a sub document is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am finding a sub document like so:

```
var incidentId = "someID1"
var alerteeId  = "someID2"

Incident.findOneQ({ _id: someID1, 'alertees._id': someID2 }, {'alertees.$': 1})
.then(function(incident) {
  var alertee = incident.alertees[0];
  alertee.responded_at = Date.now()
  return alertee.parent().saveQ().then(function(alertee) {
    console.log(alertee)
  })
})
```

It correctly finds the alertee. But when I update, it fails to save the alertee.

This only occurs if the position of the alertee in the array is NOT the first. The first Alertee in the array of alertees, is able to be found and updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax here is not "strictly" mongoose syntax, so not sure if you are implementing some other layer on top of this.

But really what you want is `.findOneAndUpdate()` as specified in the mongoose documentation. Basically that will do your whole update in one call, and you call it like this:

```
Incident.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": someID1, "alertees._id": someID2 },
    { "alertees.$.responded_at": Date.now() },
    function(err,incident) {
        if (err) throw err;    // or do something like return the error

        if ( incident != null ) {
            incident.altertees.some(function(alertee) {
                if ( alertee._id.toString() == someID2.toString() ) {
                    console.log( alertee );
                    return 1;
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log( "not found" );
        }
    }
);
```

That is the most efficient update form that will also return you the altered document. In the response callback I'm using [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) just to match the "alertee" that was updated and return as you are.

Of course that does not call any methods or hooks defined on your "schema", but for just updating a date it is unlikely you need it. If you do you can use `.findOne()` and `.save()` just as you have, but match the array element much as I have before updating instead.

---

Or as a more complete example:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var alerteeSchema = new Schema({
    "responded_at": Date
});

var incidentSchema = Schema({
    alertees: [alerteeSchema]
});

var Incident = mongoose.model( "Incident", incidentSchema );

var incident = new Incident();

var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(
    date1.valueOf() - ( date1.valueOf() % 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )
);

incident.alertees.push({ "responded_at": date1 });
incident.alertees.push({ "responded_at": date2 });

incident.save(function(err,incident) {

    if (err) throw err;
    var someID1 = incident._id;
    var someID2 = incident.alertees[1]._id;
    //var someID2 = new ObjectId();

    console.log( "before: \n" + incident );


    Incident.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": someID1, "alertees._id": someID2 },
        { "alertees.$.responded_at": Date.now() },
        function(err,incident) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (incident != null) {
                incident.alertees.some(function(alertee) {
                    console.log( "test: " + alertee );
                    if ( alertee._id.toString() == someID2.toString() ) {
                        console.log( "after: \n" + alertee );
                        return 1;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log( "not found" );
            }
        }
    );

});
```

With these results:

```
before:
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 53aba6c73b8d05ef77c2703b,
  alertees:
   [ { responded_at: Thu Jun 26 2014 14:51:19 GMT+1000 (EST),
       _id: 53aba6c73b8d05ef77c2703c },
     { responded_at: Thu Jun 26 2014 08:58:31 GMT+1000 (EST),
       _id: 53aba6c73b8d05ef77c2703d } ] }
test: { responded_at: Thu Jun 26 2014 14:51:19 GMT+1000 (EST),
  _id: 53aba6c73b8d05ef77c2703c }
test: { responded_at: Thu Jun 26 2014 14:51:19 GMT+1000 (EST),
  _id: 53aba6c73b8d05ef77c2703d }
after:
{ responded_at: Thu Jun 26 2014 14:51:19 GMT+1000 (EST),
  _id: 53aba6c73b8d05ef77c2703d }
```